# compile external library with application

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, external

So i am trying to get a C# application that i have developed that uses the Iconic Zip library, when i compile the program into an executable, and run it on another machine i get an error saying

`"Could not load file or assembly 'Iconic.Zip...' or one if its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."`

I realise that this is because the .dll is not in the same directory/expected directory as the exe.

Is there a way to bundle in the .dll to the exe through Visual Studio so that i do not have to provide the library as a seperate entity?

Comment: Copying two files instead of one isn't exactly rocket science.  A zip file is also popular to distribute programs.  You've surely run a setup.exe program before, always the best way to package a program, users expect it.  ILMerge is a popular tool.

Comment: @HansPassant one of my aims with the application is to create a single, self contained .exe that can be run from wherever the user wishes. I will definitely look into ILMerge though.